# Compatible buildpacks for Scala Playframework application

Tags: scala, playframework, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploying an sample scala playframework application to cloud foundry (https://api.run.pivotal.io)

```
$ cf push play-cf-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

But its failing with the reason

> None of the buildpacks detected a compatible application

I have tried running below command which is giving me the list if buildpack

```
cf buildpacks

java_buildpack                   2          true      false    java-buildpack-offline-cflinuxfs3-v4.31.1.zip              cflinuxfs3
go_buildpack                     6          true      false    go_buildpack-cached-cflinuxfs3-v1.9.14.zip                 cflinuxfs3
python_buildpack                 7          true      false    python_buildpack-cached-cflinuxfs3-v1.7.15.zip             cflinuxfs3
```

I assume java buildpack works for play scala app as well.

Any particular command which help me to deploy with correct buildpack or create my own buildpack.

Comment: As stated in the docs, the Java buildpack can run Play apps packaged with `play dist` or `play stage`.  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/main/docs/example-play_framework.md. Try running `cf push play-application -p path/to/play-f-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`. The first arg is the application name and `-p` tells it where to find your packaged Play app.

Comment: Yes the solution works for me what have done wrong is `$ cf push play-cf-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip` this command as we it does not have path.

Comment: Excellent. I suspected it might be that. Glad it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java buildpack has support for Play applications.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/main/docs/example-play_framework.md

As stated in the docs, the Java buildpack can run a Play apps when packaged with `play dist` or `play stage`.

In addition, it looks like the command you're using is slightly off. You need to run `cf push play-application -p path/to/play-f-demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`.

The first argument is the application name and the `-p` argument tells `cf` where to find your packaged Play app.

In this case of this question, the command being run set the application name to the name of the file but set no path, which means `cf push` will upload everything from the current directory, which is almost certainly something the Java buildpack won't know how to run.